# C++ in-class initialization of pointer-to-member makes MSVC to fail (but GCC/Clang work)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Here's a shockingly simple C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    constexpr static int A::* p = &A::a;
    virtual void f() {}
};
int main()
{
    A x; x.a = 0;
    x.*(A::p) = 1234;
    std::cout << x.a;
}
```

Even more shocking thing is that this code shows different result between GCC,Clang and MSVC.

I've tried 4 compilers

1. GCC : compiles well, prints `1234`.
2. Clang : compiles well, prints `1234`.
3. MSVC (online) : fails to compile.
4. MSVC (local) with Visual Studio 2019  : compiles well, prints `0`. (Funny thing is that if I remove `f()` then it prints `1234`.)

I'm not sure if in-class initialization of pointer-to-member with its own member is legal or not, but I believe this code is supposed to print `1234`.

Try out on *Compiler Explorer* or *Rextester*.

I have no idea who is right. (at least 4. seems to be a bug)

Edit - I found out that the difference of 3. and 4. comes from compiler option `/permissive`. But both results of `/permissive` and no-`/permissive` still differ from gcc and clang.

Comment: I'm more interested in *why* you have something like this? What is the real problem you tried to solve this way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I refined the original code to be extremely simple but enough to reproduce error. (which is proper way of posting question on stackoverflow) There's no point of this small dummy code.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The question itself is good, as is the example. I just wonder what problem you *originally* tried to solve, what made you come up with a solution like this? Or is it just plain curiosity (which is as good a reason as anything else)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's very complicated (and very different from this code), so I'll just say for packing members in template-metaprogramming. (you may extend the pointer-to-member to pointers-to-member in tuple)

Comment: GCC 4.8.4 fails to compile with segmentation fault :)

Comment: @sklott Would you try later version?

Comment: If you enable the `permissive` compiler flag in MSVC local, you would get an error (`expression did not evaluate to a constant`). Have no idea why this can happen.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Thanks. Perhaps there would be a syntactically clear way that MSVC can understand

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This is a slightly modified code, it seems worked as you expected, in Visual Studio 2019:

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a;
    constexpr static int A::* p() { return &A::a; }
    virtual void f() {}
};

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    A x;
    void* px = &x;
    x.a = 0;
    x.*(A::p()) = 1234;
    cout << x.a << endl;

    getchar();
}
```

**Update end**

---

Just tried on Visual Studio 2019, I modified code to this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    constexpr static int A::* p = &A::a;
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct B
{
    int a;
    constexpr static int B::* p = &B::a;
};

using namespace std;

void printBytes(void* p, size_t length = 16) {
    uint8_t* pu = (uint8_t*)p;
    cout << "  ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        auto val = *(pu + i);
        printf("%02x ", val);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    A x;
    void* px = &x;
    cout << "\nfor A:\n";
    printBytes(px);
    x.a = 0;
    printBytes(px);
    x.*(A::p) = 0x1234;
    printBytes(px);
    cout << x.a << endl;

    B y;
    void* py = &y;
    cout << "\nfor B:\n";
    printBytes(py);
    y.a = 0;
    printBytes(py);
    y.*(B::p) = 0x1234;
    printBytes(py);
    cout << y.a << endl;

    getchar();
}
```

the output is:

```
for A:
  fc 9c 2c 01 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 0f 40 04 09
  fc 9c 2c 01 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 0f 40 04 09
  34 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 0f 40 04 09
0

for B:
  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 60 fd 3d 01
  00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 60 fd 3d 01
  34 12 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 60 fd 3d 01
4660
```

The **B case** work as expected, but for **A case**, the output above suggests that this line:

`x.*(A::p) = 0x1234;`

wrote `0x1234` to the position where "pointer to virtual function table" occupying.

So, I suppose **the compiler of Visual Studio 2019 made a mistake** with the expression `&A::a`(get pointer to member variable) on **struct(class as well)** which has virtual member function.

Comment: Well... then isn't this a critical bug..?

Comment: I don't know how serious it is, but I think it can be work out with a detour: change `constexpr static int A::* p = &A::a;` to `constexpr static int A::* PA() { return &A::a; }`